# is there a way to produce a similar table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, pdftex, booktabs

I would like to produce a similar table to (see the picture below) in LaTeX, overleaf..
I read the docs for creating tables in overleaf, and it does not seem capable of producing the same table... any idea how I can go about that?

[image: 1]

That is my full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{lavender}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.98}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{35pt}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareSIUnit\angstrom{\text {Å}}
\ifdefined\qtyproduct\else
  \NewCommandCopy\qtyproduct\SI
\fi
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\graphicspath{ {images/} }


\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figs/} }
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{section}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{table}[]
    \caption{Parameters for protein solvation calculations using APBSmem}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
        Parameter & Value  \\
        \midrule
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Calculation type & Protein solvation \\
        Grid Dimensions & $\qtyproduct{289 x 289 x 257}{\angstrom}$ \\
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Coarse Grid Lengths & $\qtyproduct{202.889 x 202.915 x 185.759}{\angstrom}$ \\
        Fine Grid Lengths &   $\qtyproduct{139.347 x 139.362 x 129.27}{\angstrom}$ \\
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Counter-Ions & 1.0, 0.154, 1.65 \\
                     & -1.0, 0.154, 1.67 \\
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Protein Dielectric & 2.0 \\
        Solvent Dielectric & 80.0 \\
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Membrane Dielectric & 8.0 \\
        Headgroup Dielectric & 80.0 \\
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Boundary Conditions & Focus \\
        Solvent probe radius (srad) & 1.4 \\
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Surface sphere density (sdens) & 10 \\
        Temperature & 298.15 \\
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Z-position of membrane bottom & -23.9 \\
        Membrane thickness & 47.8 \\
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Headgroup thickness & -- \\
        Upper exclusion radius & 0 \\
        \rowcolor{cyan}
        Lower exclusion radius & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

and below is the produced table, things I wish to change are: 1) make Table 1. In the title bold, that is not trivial though with \textbf because it doubles the title...

2. as you see in the picture, "39" is the page number, because the table is so lengthy, any idea how to tackle that?
3. add a line to the left with the same thickness (as in picture 1)

[image: 2]

Comment: Could you expand you code to a [mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This way, we'll know what package you use.

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: Please edit it again and take out the stuff that's unrelated to the table; read Alain's link about creating a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my attempt using the [tabularray package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=en), which I recommend for any complex tables.

It comes pretty close; though following your lead I used cyan rows rather than gray. (Muted a little as yours are too bright for my taste.) Easy enough to make them gray if you prefer.

If the table is going to be big enough that it might span pages, I wouldn't use a table environment (float) at all.

The package has its own means for inserting a caption above the table and repeating it on each page, but there's a problem with this particular table in that you want to include the caption inside the table so as to have the left border of the table include it. So rather than using the facilities of the package, I suppressed the usual caption and manually increase the table counter and reset it back afterwards. That's not super elegant, and maybe someone can think of a better way.

Since it's a longtblr it should span multiple pages fine (without overlapping the footer). It'll even repeat the header rows. See the [package documentation](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) for more info.

(I removed all the stuff unrelated to the issue. However, note that you're loading xcolor twice in your current document. Don't do that.)

I inserted plenty of comments so you can see what each thing does and tweak if need be.

**EDIT**: Below is my suggestion if you want the table to be able to span multiple pages. If you want to squeeze it into one, I make an alternative suggestion below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% sans serif font
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

% suppress normal caption as we will use a caption row instead
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}
% increase table counter for caption inside row; add label
\noindent\refstepcounter{table}\label{table:1}%
\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec={|[2pt]% two point line on left border of table
    @{\kern0pt}% small whitespace after that line
    Q[l,colsep=0pt,rightsep=4em]% first column, left aligned, 
    % no space on left, large space on right
    Q[l,colsep=0pt]},% second column, left aligned, no space on left
    rowhead=3,% first three rows are header and should be repeated
    % if the table spans pages
    row{1} = {abovesep=2ex,belowsep=2ex},% extra vertical space 1st row
    row{2} = {abovesep=0.5ex,belowsep=0.5ex},% blank row #2
    row{3} = {abovesep=1.5ex,belowsep=1.5ex,preto={\bfseries}},% row 3
    % has some extra space and text in it is bold
    row{4-Z} = {abovesep=0.8ex,belowsep=0.4ex},% remainder of rows have
    % a little extra vertical space
    row{even[4-Z]} = {cyan!40!white},% even rows 4-on have cyan background
    % use, e.g., black!40!white for gray
    hline{2} = {2pt}, % 2 point horizontal line above row 2
    hline{2} = {1}{1}{leftpos=-0.2}, % a little gap on the left of that line
    hline{3} = {1pt}, % thinner line above row 3
    hline{3} = {1}{1}{leftpos=-0.2}, % also has a small gap on left
    hline{4} = {0.7pt},% even thinner line above row 4
    hline{4} = {1}{1}{leftpos=-0.2},% also has a small gap on left
    hline{Z} = {1.5pt},% medium line at bottom of table
    hline{Z} = {1}{1}{leftpos=-0.2}% small gap on left
}
    % the first cell is the caption cell, spans two olumns
    \SetCell[c=2]{c}\textbf{Table \thetable.} Parameters for protein solvation calculations using APBSmem.  & \\
                    & \\ % empty row
    Parameter & Value  \\ % header row
    Calculation type & Protein solvation \\
    Grid Dimensions & 289 $\times$ 289 $\times$ 257 \\
    Coarse Grid Lengths & 202.889 $\times$ 202.915 $\times$ 185.759 \\
    Fine Grid Lengths &   139.347 $\times$ 139.362 $\times$ 129.27 \\
    Counter-Ions & 1.0, 0.154, 1.65 \\
                 & $-$1.0, 0.154, 1.67 \\
    Protein Dielectric & 2.0 \\
    Solvent Dielectric & 80.0 \\
    Membrane Dielectric & 8.0 \\
    Headgroup Dielectric & 80.0 \\
    Boundary Conditions & Focus \\
    Solvent probe radius (srad) & 1.4 \\
    Surface sphere density (sdens) & 10 \\
    Temperature & 298.15 \\
    Z-position of membrane bottom & $-$23.9 \\
    Membrane thickness & 47.8 \\
    Headgroup thickness & -- \\
    Upper exclusion radius & 0 \\
    Lower exclusion radius & 0
\end{longtblr}
% undo extra increase to table counter
\addtocounter{table}{-1}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample table]

**EDIT**: If you don't want to allow it to span multiple pages, then you *should* use a float, i.e., a `table` environment, and then use the simpler `tblr` environment rather than `longtblr` on the inside.

Be sure to use a placement specifier (here `[h!tb]`) with the float, as you didn't in your sample code.

You still need to manually add the caption and increase the counter to keep it inside the table. However, because the `tblr` environment doesn't increase the table counter on its own, you won't need to reset it at the end.

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% sans serif font
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!tb]
% increase table counter for caption inside row; add label
\noindent\refstepcounter{table}\label{table:1}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={|[2pt]% two point line on left border of table
    @{\kern0pt}% small whitespace after that line
    Q[l,colsep=0pt,rightsep=4em]% first column, left aligned, 
    % no space on left, large space on right
    Q[l,colsep=0pt]},% second column, left aligned, no space on left
    row{1} = {abovesep=2ex,belowsep=2ex},% extra vertical space 1st row
    row{2} = {abovesep=0.5ex,belowsep=0.5ex},% blank row #2
    row{3} = {abovesep=1.5ex,belowsep=1.5ex,preto={\bfseries}},% row 3
    % has some extra space and text in it is bold
    row{4-Z} = {abovesep=0.8ex,belowsep=0.4ex},% remainder of rows have
    % a little extra vertical space
    row{even[4-Z]} = {cyan!40!white},% even rows 4-on have cyan background
    % use, e.g., black!40!white for gray
    hline{2} = {2pt}, % 2 point horizontal line above row 2
    hline{2} = {1}{1}{leftpos=-0.2}, % a little gap on the left of that line
    hline{3} = {1pt}, % thinner line above row 3
    hline{3} = {1}{1}{leftpos=-0.2}, % also has a small gap on left
    hline{4} = {0.7pt},% even thinner line above row 4
    hline{4} = {1}{1}{leftpos=-0.2},% also has a small gap on left
    hline{Z} = {1.5pt},% medium line at bottom of table
    hline{Z} = {1}{1}{leftpos=-0.2}% small gap on left
}
    % the first cell is the caption cell, spans two olumns
    \SetCell[c=2]{c}\textbf{Table \thetable.} Parameters for protein solvation calculations using APBSmem.  & \\
                    & \\ % empty row
    Parameter & Value  \\ % header row
    Calculation type & Protein solvation \\
    Grid Dimensions & 289 $\times$ 289 $\times$ 257 \\
    Coarse Grid Lengths & 202.889 $\times$ 202.915 $\times$ 185.759 \\
    Fine Grid Lengths &   139.347 $\times$ 139.362 $\times$ 129.27 \\
    Counter-Ions & 1.0, 0.154, 1.65 \\
                 & $-$1.0, 0.154, 1.67 \\
    Protein Dielectric & 2.0 \\
    Solvent Dielectric & 80.0 \\
    Membrane Dielectric & 8.0 \\
    Headgroup Dielectric & 80.0 \\
    Boundary Conditions & Focus \\
    Solvent probe radius (srad) & 1.4 \\
    Surface sphere density (sdens) & 10 \\
    Temperature & 298.15 \\
    Z-position of membrane bottom & $-$23.9 \\
    Membrane thickness & 47.8 \\
    Headgroup thickness & -- \\
    Upper exclusion radius & 0 \\
    Lower exclusion radius & 0
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(The output should look more or less exactly like the above, just confined to one page.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried reproducing it, but the table is now split into 2 pages and this is something i do not like...also "continued on next page" line is not something nice to see in a document.. did you produce it on one single page?

Comment: The above does fit on one page for me. If it doesn't for you, it's because you have other stuff on the page that I have no way of knowing about, but I thought you *wanted* it to be able to span pages. You can customize or remove the "continued on next page" message. See the package documentation. But I'll edit the answer to add an alternative if you want to try to squeeze it on one page.

Comment: OK, I added an alternative suggestion. If that doesn't work for you, you'll need to edit your mwe to include whatever is above the table, and fully explain how you'd prefer to handle potential overflow.